# Cambiar el style de texto de un textarea con StyledEditorKit

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo un JMenuBar con un menu que tiene un boton que debería cambiar el texto seleccionado a negritam pero no funciona... no se como hacer que el `JTextArea` sepa que le quiero cambiar el estilo de la fuente

este es el codigo

```
class Window extends JFrame{
    JTextArea textarea;
    JMenuItem bold;

    Window(){
        setTitle("Procesador de Texto");
        setSize(600, 400);
        setJMenuBar( new Navbar() );
        setTextArea();
    }

    public void setTextArea(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        textarea = new JTextArea();

        panel.add(textarea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panel);
    }

    private class Navbar extends JMenuBar{
        Navbar(){
            JMenu menuStyle = new JMenu("Estilo");

            bold = new JMenuItem("Negrita");

            menuStyle.add(bold);

            bold.addActionListener( new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction() );

            add(menuStyle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya intentaste?: bold.setFont(bold.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));

Comment: Yo quiero ponerle un bold al texto del JTextArea

Comment: textarea.setFont(textarea.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));

Comment: Aja y en que momento funciona con el boton?

Comment: Ah ya entendí, quieres que con un botón cambiarle el estilo?? Entonces el código que te puse debe de ir adentro del listener del `JMenuItem bold`. Es decir, adentro de esta funcion `StyledEditorKit.BoldAction()`

Comment: Lo termine solucionando después!! yo estaba usando un JTextArea, pero lo cambie por un JTextPane y funciono